# Регулярные выражения при поиске в Excel

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel

У меня в таблице есть примерно такие записи:

```
№ 1
№ 2
№4
№5
```

Мне необходимо сделать поиск-замена и поставить пробел после знака `№`, чтобы все были одинаковы. Это, как мне кажется, надо реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений. 
Как правильно задать такое регулярное выражение для поиска строк, где после `№` идет символ, не равный пробелу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, проще?

Выделить диапазон данных, *НАЙТИ*-№-*ЗАМЕНИТЬ*-№ (номер с пробелом)-*ОК*;

*НАЙТИ* -  (два пробела)-*ЗАМЕНИТЬ*- (один пробел)-*ОК*

Comment: Мне необходимо поставить один пробел туда, где № и порядковый номер написанны `слитно`.

Comment: Я Вам это и предложил: первым действием к № добавляем пробел, вторым действием убираем пробел там, где получилось два рядом.

Comment: Более того, можно воспользоваться функцией split для удаления лишних пробелов или сразу добавлять пробел там, где следующий после № идет НЕ пробел.